# Maximize Volume + Surface of a Cone that fits in a Sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-optimization

The purpose in this problem is to find the radius r and the height h of a cone that maximize the sum of the volume and the surface area of the cone in a sphere with radius R. The sum of these values is calculated as

```
      V+A = πr^2h/3+πr^2+πr√(h^2+r^2)
```

The optimization problem becomes:

```
 Maximize:       V+A = πr^2h/3+πr^2+πr√(h^2+r^2)

 Subject to             h<2R ,   r<R
```

I am not sure if the final form of the problem is correct or not. If it is correct, which algorithm can be applied to solve this optimization problem? Thanks.

Image : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lhpADqevT5bHgkmUbc6sIQA7APtMGgH7

Comment: Express the volume plus area as a function of the single variable $z$, take the derivative with respect to $z$, set it to zero to find the maximizing value of $z$.

Comment: You've formatted it quite nicely, but in the future its better to use MathJax. here's a quick tutorial https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference